# TypeOrm subscriber between projects

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have two node projects that read/write on the same database. To simplify, A and B are the two projects. They both use TypeOrm.

Project A is an API that have subscribers on some entities that should send a websockets every time a new row is added to the corresponding table.
Project B is the one that actually saves the rows in the database.

The issue is that B sending data to the database does not trigger A subscribers. I tried adding data from project A and everything worked fine.

How could I trigger a function on project A when project B adds data to the database ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, both projects needs be run by the same process. This is mandatory since TypeOrm subscribers are not fired when data is written/read in the database but rather when the DataSource object is used.

So you basically have to share the same instance of DataSource between your projects. In NestJs, this can be done by extracting DataSource from the appModule this way :

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger: new CustomLogger('NEST'),
});

const appModule = app.select(AppModule);
const data = appModule.get(DataSource);
```

Once you have the DataSource, feed it to the other project. When one of them adds data to the database, it will trigger any subscriber in the other.